# Circular reference between two objects

Tags: rust

Suppose you have an enum `A`, that can contain references to another enum `B`. `B` can also contain references to `A`. How do you organize the lifetimes?

The following is non-working code:

```rust
struct B<'b>(&'b A);
struct A<'a>(&'a B);
```

As you can see, the goal is to have a struct A with references to B and B with references to A. However, this would create a cyclical dependency.

An example is a cell value that may be part of a larger array. The array needs to have references to cell values, but a cell value may contain references to other arrays.

Comment: The question you need to ask yourself is who owns the data. Having an `A` which points *back* to its owner is actually quite difficult under Rust's ownership model, though fortunately you can usually structure your code to avoid such things.

Comment: Long story short: `struct B<'b>(&'b A)` implies `struct B<'b>(&'b A<'b>)`, which means that `A<'b>` is a `struct A<'b>(&'b B<'b>)`. No surprises here: A circular reference only works if the entire structure lives forever. There can never be one reference that is shorter than any other, because that would mean that longer-lived references contained shorter-lived references, which is not allowed. There is no solution using references. You can use `Rc::weak`-"references" for such models, or resort to different structures alltogether. But references only work if they boil down to `'static`.

Comment: As long as the cell contains references to *other* arrays, but not the array in which it is contained itself, this should not be a problem.

Comment: You can do that if some outside type owns both `A` and `B`, or if one is `Arc` and the other is `Weak`.

Comment: How do you do it if an outside type owns both `A` and `B`?